# What does poetry enact according to Heidegger?

Tags: aesthetics, heidegger

The following idea is cited approving in a book I just read

[image]

- Derrida, Heidegger, Blanchot, by Timothy Clark

But on an earlier page the same author says

[image]

In what way can a poem be "nothing but its own evocation" but not an incarnation? The two words are close, if not identical in every sense. However in practice I can't see the difference.

It may be germane to add that Heidegger claims that poetry (which is a bringing into being) should be interpreted with a mind to dispose of that interpretation; I think I even read the claim that his desire for interpretation (close reading etc.) contradicts his aesthetics!

> For the sake of preserving what has been put into the poem, the elucidation of the poem must strive to make itself superfluous. The
>   last, but also the most difficult step of every interpretation
>   [Auslegung], consists in its disappearing, along with its
>   elucidations, before the pure presence of the poem. The poem, which
>   then stands in its own right, itself throws light directly on the
>   other poems.

- Elucidations of Holderin's poetry, cited in The Philosophy of
  Improvisation By Gary Peter

Can what is being said here be pinned down?

Comment: one reason could be that it evokes through a rejection of its meaning. but when could that be properly called "poetry"

Comment: Enactment, here, seems to be opposed to Representation; representations refer, which is why, I suppose Enactment being an opposite, refers without a reference.